# Add target="_blank" to RouteLink when routename is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't seem to find the answer to my problem below.

I'm trying to use the [RouteLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx) method with a `target="_blank"` attribute.

I've tried the following but it doesn't give the expected output.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Display text","My_Route_Name",new{Id="AGuid", target="_blank"}
```

**Actual output**

```
<a href="/my_route_url/AGuid?target=_blank">Display text</a>
```

**Expected output**

```
<a href="/my_route_url/AGuid" target="_blank">Display text</a>
```

Any ideas, suggestions?

*ps. search on stack overflow didn't bring anything up.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like as below

```
@Html.RouteLink("Display text", "My_Route_Name", new { Id = "AGuid" }, new { target = "_blank" });
```

Comment: This is the solution I've used. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try with `htmlAttributes:` and specify `null` as the 3rd param value, because on 3rd param it refers to `Object RouteValues` rather than `Object htmlAttributes`

**Params**

```
public static MvcHtmlString RouteLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    Object routeValues, //this is getting targeted in your case
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

**Changes**

```
@Html.RouteLink("Display text","My_Route_Name",new { Id = "AGuid" }, htmlAttributes: new {target="_blank"})
```

Or

```
@Html.RouteLink("Display text","My_Route_Name",new {Id="AGuid"},new {target="_blank"})
```

**[`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470912(v=vs.118).aspx)**

Comment: +1 for targeting me into the right direction. I've used the solution like Pragnesh Khalas suggested though. The id has to go into the routeValues and the target into the htmlAttributes (my preference). I'm sure your solution will work as well.

Comment: Then I believe @PragneshKhalas is efficient as I was under impression that `id` is related to element `id` instead of making it fit in `route values`. Anyways. I will update the same, but yea you can mark his answer..

Comment: Aah, no, the id mentioned here is not a html attribute but an object id like a guid from a database. stupid enough I can't mark 2 answers as a solution as you deserve it as well then :-|

Comment: No probs buddy.. :) Appreciate the kindness.. :) I just got confused. Happy coding.. :)